# How to use variable variables in class variables and function arguments

Tags: php, variable-variables

This is what I want to do:

```
class Contacts {

    private $_plural = 'contacts';
    private $_single = 'contact';
    private $_factory = 'contactfactory';
    private $_model = 'contact_model';

    private $_idname = $_plural . "Id";

    function a($$_idname = 0) {

    }
}
```

These two lines:

```
private $_idname = $_plural . "Id";
```

and

```
function a ($$_idname = 0) {
```

aren't working. Why? And how can I fix this?

*EDIT*

About the function argument:

If $_idname = "contactId" I want the argument to be $contactId. That's why I have two dollar signs there. This might be not the correct way to handle this, but this is what I want to accomplish.

Comment: Firstly remove the second dollar in the variable name: function a ($_idname = 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change

```
private $_idname = $_plural . "Id";
```

to

```
private $_idname;
public function __construct(){
  $this->_idname = $this->_plural.'Id';
}
```

first.

Not seeing enough in `function a`. Probably more like:

```
public function a($really = 'What is the point of those underscores?'){
  ${$this->_idname} = $really; // local $contacts var holds $really
}
```

I'm really guessing that you want to have a method that will automatically change your instantiated Object property. You don't need a variable variable for that. If you want to affect a variable which you are passing as an argument it's `&$yourVar`. There is no need to pass a property of an instantiated Object to its own method, since you already have access to it within the method with `$this->yourVar`.

Comment: $this->_plural, doesn't work either. I get the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE)

about the function variable. I'll edit my question

Answer (score 2):

According to [PHP's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php), you must initialize a class attribute with a constant value:

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization **must be a constant value**--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

A fix for this would be using a class constructor:

```
function __construct() {
    $this->_idname = $this->_plural . "Id";
}
```

Also, you can't use [dynamic variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) names on functions or methods:

> Please note that variable variables cannot be used with PHP's Superglobal arrays within functions or class methods. **The variable $this is also a special variable that cannot be referenced dynamically.**

Comment: I indeed thought about doing it the way in the constructor, but I thought it might be cleaner and clearer doing it there where I declare the class variables. Thanks for the information anyways.